# Increment array value by 1 in php

Tags: php

I have a simple array $rating=[0,0,0,0,0]; and I need to increment the values by 1. I have a value $val=2. if value matches to 2 then I want to increment $rating[1] value by 1. (Just example, but increment is not happening)

```
$rating=[0,0,0,0,0];
$val = 2;
if($val ==2){
    $rating[1]++;
}
```

after this $rating[1] suppose to increment and has to become 1(i.e $rating must be [0,1,0,0,0]). its not working!!

Comment: maybe $rating[1] is a string and not a number ? what return $rating[1]++ ?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean exactly?

Comment: [Works well enough](https://3v4l.org/4gElt)

Comment: What does it output when you add `var_dump($rating)` after your `if` statement ? And what about `var_dump($row['rating'])` ?

Comment: check what mark given.your code must be working

Comment: please read qn again

Comment: @shreedharbhat `if column value matches to 2` but you are comparing var `$val` to `2`, what is always true.

Comment: Your code works correctly.

Comment: Your code (as shown) works.... what else are you doing that might affect the result?

Comment: @MarkBaker what you said is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know what mistake I was doing! It was inside while loop and thas y getting initiated again and again. The

## best way

```
$rating=[0,0,0,0,0];
$val = 2;
if($val ==2){
    $rating[1]++;
}
echo $rating;
```

this gives the output [0,1,0,0,0]

Answer (score 2):

It's working Fine. like below

```
<?php
$rating = array('0','0','0','0','0');
$val = 2;
if($val ==2){
  $rating[1]++;
}
print_r($rating);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )
```

Comment: You don't need to make those values string unnecessarily. The OP's code actually works fine. Your code is kind of misleading that the code you've written only works for string. Maybe the `print_r` you've written might have been help for him. Both of your code is same except converting those values to string and `print_r` statement.

Comment: Yes Rights! my friends

Comment: This is the exact same code as in the question (except for the difference in defining the array and the print_r) so I don't see how this answers the question. If the code in the question works, then the question should be questioned or answers given why this might not work in some settings, IMHO.